# Robot framework, how to immediately return from test case after page contains

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, tdd, robotframework, acceptance-testing

I have the following test case

```
Login
    Open Browser And Go To Login Page
    Do Login
    Page Should Not Contain    Error Login
    Wait Until Page Contains    Logged In
    [Teardown]    Close Browser
```

Even though login succeeds right away and the text "Logged In" is immediately present, test case hangs for a minute before closing the browser and returning successfully.

Why is that, and how do I return immediately after the page contains the text?

Comment: The extra time is taken by Close Browser command. Remove that and check.

Comment: the log should tell you which keyword is taking the extra time.

Comment: I use to write directly Close Browser without any [Teardown] and for me close immediately